# Вставка изображения в canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, изображения

При вставке изображения в canvas оно получается растянутым.
Вот сам код http://jsbin.com/aceyeCa/1/edit
Как сделать его нормальным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно задавать размеры не через style/css, а через свойства, т.е.:

```
$('canvas').prop({
    width: img.width,
    height: img.height 
});
```